# Set Interval Issue on Counter

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval

I need to set up a simple counter in a div element, I've done a simplified version of the code below but the counter doesn't fire, and I can't work out why it isn't working

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/rzJXpB

Code is below.

JS

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

function theCounter() {
  var counter = 0;
  div1.innerHTML = counter;
  counter++;

}

setInterval(theCounter, 1000);
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Put `var counter = 0` outside the function: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdYXVP. Otherwise, you're just reseting the counter every time you call your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter does fire, but you are resetting its value every time it is called. You could pull the `counter` variable out of the `theCounter` function to make it work.

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var counter = 0;

function theCounter() { 
  div1.innerHTML = counter;
  counter+=1;

}

setInterval(theCounter, 1000);
```

Here's the updated pen: https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/mMXNjp